# dara.append(row) is not defined

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv
FirstName = 0
Surname = 1
Grade = 2

def read_csv_data(assessment):
data = [ ]
with open('UASHSDDP1efiles.csv', mode='r') as 
csv_data:
records = csv.reader(csv_data, delimiter=',')

for row in records:
data.append(row)

    def find_max(student_grades):
max_grade = 200
top_grade = None

for i in (student_grades):
    grade = float(i[Grade])
    if grade >= max_grade:
        max_grade = grade
        top_grade = i
    return top_grade

def write_top_grade(assessment, top_grade):
    print(top_grade[FirstName] + " " + top_grade[Surname] + " " + top_grade[Grade])
    with open(assessment, 'w', newline=+' ') as data:
        data.write (top_grade[FirstName] + " " + top_grade[Surname] + " " + top_grade[Grade])

student_grades = read_csv_data('UASHSDDP1efiles.csv')
top_grade = find_max(student_grades)
write_top_grade("UASHSDDP1efiles.csv", top_grade)
```

#I haven't had much experience with python and I get the error that data is not defined in my program. I am trying to link a CSV file into my program then have it read and add data within the csv file. I also want my code to be able to give an output of some data too.

Comment: I suggest editing the question so that you point out the error and reformat the code since it doesn't look well in the preview and the code is split in several parts.

Comment: Ahh, I will do thank you!

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct? also you don't return data in read_csv_data

Comment: I have fixed the indentation now I have the error "I/O operation on closed file." but at the same area as the pervious error. What do you mean I can't return data in read_csv_data?

Comment: Could you edit your question with the new indentation please? By "also you don't return data in read_csv_data" I mean that your read_csv_data is not returning the "data" variable

Answer (score 0):

```
def write_top_grade(assessment, top_grade):
   print(top_grade[FirstName] + " " + top_grade[Surname] + " " + top_grade[Grade])
   with open(assessment, 'w') as csv_file:
       data = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',')
       data.writerow(top_grade[FirstName] + " " + top_grade[Surname] + " " + top_grade[Grade])
```

writing in a CSV file is done using the writer object.Then you can write inside the file using writerow() or writerows() based on the code conditions.